# how does plesk asp.net website restart without affecting others in the shared pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, plesk, application-pool

I have multiple asp.net sites in plesk shared hosting, and if I were to modify the `web.config` for one site it will **restart**, and the first request will take about 10 to 15 seconds.

**However this restart doesn't affect the rest of my websites which are in the same pool.**

Does plesk do any additional work to handle individual site restart in a shared pool, or is it all handled by IIS ?

I'm wondering whether the quantity of sites on the server, in the same pool, affects the time needed for the individual site to restart.

Edit: I have multiple asp.net core sites, one mvc5 and one web-forms, but the one I'm testing is ASP.net Core with `hostingModel="OutOfProcess"` in `web.config` otherwise it won't work in the shared pool. The site is lightweight (the default ASP.net Core site created in VS2022 File -> New -> ASP.net Core)

Comment: App pool can have multiple sites in it and the sites can be started/stopped without affecting all sites in the pool. IIS handles this. The problem with too many sites in one pool is that one bad site can bring down the whole pool. I do not think performance is affected by the number of sites in a pool.

Comment: @Vasya, thank you, any idea what else could make the first request slow if it's not the amount of sites in the same pool, the site I'm testing with is almost empty, the default asp.net core template from VS2022 (File => new -> asp.net core).

Comment: You tagged this as ASP.NET. Is it Web Forms? MVC? ASP.NET Core? Web Forms has to do a lot of precompilation steps when the site is accessed for the first time, though there are [techniques to precompile upon deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs).

Comment: The initial request can be slow because IIS needs to create a worker process to serve your site. You may want to adjust IIS configuration (it may not be possible as you are using hosting service). Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Comment: If you don't give more details, there isn't much to discuss further. While many sites can live in the same application pool and the worker process(es) of this pool take care of all incoming requests, each site does take a portion of the worker process resources and restarting a site has an impact there. The actual impact is closely related to the technology used by that site (classic ASP/ASP.NET/ASP.NET Core/PHP varies a lot). Sites are isolated, but sharing the same process can impact performance.

Comment: @LexLi the site I'm testing (changing web.config to trigger restart) is ASP.net Core latest version (default asp.net core template from VS2022 (File => new -> asp.net core)), using `hostingModel="OutOfProcess"` in web.config otherwise it won't work in plesk shared pool

Comment: @mason multiple ASP.net Core sites with `hostingModel="OutOfProcess"` in `web.config` and one MVC 5 site, and one web-forms, but I'm testing the changing of the web.config to restart on a asp.net core one

Comment: If all your sites are hosting ASP.NET Core web apps in [out-of-process mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-6.0), then the worker process(es) of the shared application pool just works as a reverse proxy where the ASP.NET Core module loaded into memory takes care of spinning out new ASP.NET Core processes to load your web apps and process incoming requests.

Restarting a single site there has very little impact on IIS worker process (w3wp.exe), but does include a step to shut down previous ASP.NET Core processes.